# How do I fill in lowercase words with NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I have code to identify the lowercase names in the dataframe:

```py
df[df.name.str.islower().fillna(False)]
```

How can I replaces these values with NaN?

I replaced other values with `replace(variable, np.nan)`:

```py
df[df.name.str.islower().fillna(False)].replace(variable, np.nan)
```

But what variable would I put in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us using `mask`

```
df.name=df.name.mask(df.name.str.islower().fillna(False))
```

Or `loc`

```
df.loc[df.name.str.islower().fillna(False),'name']=np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loc.  For all columns in dataframe:

```
s ='''
   hi MOM
   WHATS up
   '''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+', header=None)

for col in df:
    df.loc[df[col].str.islower(), col] = pd.np.nan

       0    1
0    NaN  MOM
1  WHATS  NaN
```